# RubyXL returns HEX Cell code while read a cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubyxl

I am trying read a book with RubyXL, but always return me a Hex code like: 
`#<RubyXL::Cell:0x007f8b597c4390>`

```
workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse("issues.xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook[0]
        worksheet.extract_data  # Produces a simple rectangular array that consists only of cell values (rather than the Cell objects)
        worksheet = workbook[0]
        #worksheet.sheet_data[0][0] # Returns cell A1 in the worksheet
        logger.info worksheet[17][4]
```

Is necessary return the string text in the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is getting the actual cell not it's value. To get the cell value, do this:

```
logger.info worksheet[17][4].value
```

You might need the cell for other information such as the cell styling:

```
logger.info worksheet[17][4].font_name
logger.info worksheet[17][4].font_color
logger.info worksheet[17][4].font_size
logger.info worksheet[17][4].border_top
logger.info worksheet[17][4].is_bolded
logger.info worksheet[17][4].is_italicized
logger.info worksheet[17][4].is_struckthrough
logger.info worksheet[17][4].is_underlined
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to_a in the end and it will solve your issue.